# woocommerce_login_redirect to cart if not empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

Ok, this is strange, hear me out:

```
function ts_redirect_login( $redirect, $user){


if(!WC()->cart->is_empty()){
        $redirect = wc_get_cart_url();
}
else{
        $redirect = get_home_url();
}


return $redirect;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'ts_redirect_login', 10, 2 );
```

This works if the user browses the site(not logged in), adds an item and logs in. After log in he is redirected to cart.

This does not work if a user was adding items to cart while logged in, logs out leaves the site and comes back to log in. After log in it redirects the user to the homepage as if there are no items in the cart. Once logged in if I go to the cart it is not empty but the redirect didn't happen.

So my question is: How do I redirect the user who added items in a prior session when he logs in?

var_dump only shows false for is_empty() if I add an item not logged in which makes sense, it can't know as which user I will log in and if I have products in the cart. But once I do log in, cant I be redirected to cart if I have items in it?

Comment: This did not work if a user was adding items to the cart while logged in - because this is triggerd when the user trying to login. - What you really want todo?

Comment: If a user logs into the site and has products in the cart redirect to cart, else redirect to homepage

Comment: working, thank you very much! didn't know about _woocommerce_persistent_cart_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ts_redirect_login( $redirect, $user ) {

    $saved_cart = '';

    $saved_cart_meta = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_' . get_current_blog_id(), true );

    if ( isset( $saved_cart_meta[ 'cart' ] ) ) {
        $saved_cart = array_filter( (array) $saved_cart_meta[ 'cart' ] );
    }

    if ( $saved_cart || !WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
        $redirect = wc_get_cart_url();
    } else {
        $redirect = get_home_url();
    }
    return $redirect;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'ts_redirect_login', 10, 2 );
```

This is what you are looking for